# How do we find the critical points of the function $f(x) = (x-3)(x-19)^{3}$?

Tags: calculus

I have trouble finding critical points in $(x-3)(x-19)^{3}$ which has critical points of $19$ and $7$ found in the derivative $4(x−19)^{4}(x−7)$. I have only been able to find $19$ and $3$ from the derivative $(x-3)*3(x-19)^{2} + (x-19)^{3}$ but only $19$ was correct. How can I simplify the equation to find the other critical point?

Comment: How'd you get the $(x-7)$ term?

Comment: I used a derivative calculator to find the (x-7) because I was not able to solve the problem. The second equation is what I had which only shows 19 as a critical point. I want to know how the two terms in the second equation are simplified to find (x-7) since this is also a critical point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, notice that

\begin{align*}
f(x) & = (x-3)(x-19)^{3}\\\\
& = (x - 3 - 16 + 16)(x-19)^{3}\\\\
& = (x-19)(x-19)^{3} + 16(x-19)^{3}\\\\
& = (x-19)^{4} + 16(x-19)^{3}
\end{align*}

Consequently,
\begin{align*}
f'(x) = 4(x-19)^{3} + 48(x-19)^{2} = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow 4(x-19)^{2}(x - 19 + 12) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x = 19)\vee(x = 7)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I am understanding it a little now, but how did you find 16 in the second step?

Comment: I chose the number 16 in order to reach 19.